# How to not light certain objects in unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I have been working on a small unity project which uses limited view. The issue is that the assets I add into the scene seem to be automatically lit and I'm not sure how to change this. I am using a Universal Render Pipeline. [The project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMoKv.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can create new unlit material (In inspector) for your sprite and assign your game objects, with this way it should work.